# Selectively Formatting Small Dollar Amounts with Cents

Tags: excel-formula

In reporting revenue figures for various accounts, most dollar amounts exceed tens of thousands of dollars per week.  However, a few accounts occasionally report values

To expand the cents, I found this formatting condition:  [>=1]#,##0;[<1]

However, I lose the "accounting" formatting (dollar sign).

How can I modify this formatting condition to reflect "$" accounting?

(In other words, I need a formatting condition that displays both a dollar sign and cents for values

Comment: Sorry... in other words, how do I format dollar values <$1.00 with cents, while leaving the rest as whole dollars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add custom format  Type: `[<1].00¢;$0.00_¢` and for showing both at the same time Type: `[<1].00¢;$0.00¢`

The result:
[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMMEkX3ufeHh7UGhcg8SYMpygKDHcJrUvQAMW7wYqTk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PharmacyEngineer You are welcome, accept the answer if it answers your question.